# JSF2.0 View State ID for QA Load Tool

Tags: jsf-2, load-testing

We are using JSF2 in our application. For every JSF page request, there is a hidden field `javax.faces.ViewState` issued by server. This is a new id for every page request every time. This value needs to be passed back to the server for next page request.

```
<input id="javax.faces.ViewState" type="hidden" 
   autocomplete="off" value="3120911944178727151:-831154453296813769"
   name="javax.faces.ViewState"/>
```

In load testing, we have issues in passing this value for HTTP request.

We are using QALoad tool for load testing, which simulates the http request of the page with all the required input fields. In that case, if we pass  the old  viewState Id value or pass the empty value or skip passing the field, the request is throwing `ViewExpiredException`.

Is there any way to bypass this `viewStateId` field for load testing or any other better approach?

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: I have never used QALoad, but can't you just configure it to maintain the HTTP session? Then all session-related problems should go away.

Comment: It maintains the same HTTP session .but should we need to pass the viewStateId for every requests..

Comment: That's correct. Doesn't QALoad do it? Well .. You might want to look in its manual how to include hidden fields, or look for another stress test tool like JMeter.

Answer (score 2):

Use Jmeter as a load testing tool
Configure page URL's in Jmeter to test
Add Post processor --> XPath Extractor in Jmeter to extract view id on runtime

- Reference name= ViewState
- value = "//input[@id='javax.faces.ViewState']/@value"

Add ViewState parameter in every page within Jmeter and value of that parameter will be ${ViewState} this will fetch dynamic view id with every page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the value of this field from a previous response and pass it along with the request.  This allows the server to get the right value for the current session. It might come from a header (e.g. the Set-Cookie header) or it may be found in the page content. I am not versed in QA Load, but any decent load testing tool must be able to do this.